# How to combine two interface with a type which has different attribute type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I tried to combine two interface with a type like the following, I tried to do that with the intersection of Admin & User, not just re-define the type again, is there a way to do this ?

```js
// Define type PowerUser which should have all fields
// from both User and Admin (except for type),
// and also have type 'powerUser' "without" duplicating
// all the fields in the code.
/*
const example: PowerUser = {
  type: "powerUser",
  age: 20,
  name: max,
  occupation: "FE",
  role: "ma"
}

*/

interface User {
  type: "user";
  name: string;
  age: number;
  occupation: string;
}

interface Admin {
  type: "admin";
  name: string;
  age: number;
  role: string;
}

type PowerUser = (User | Admin) & { type: "poweruser"}; // not working !!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Omit` !

```
interface User {
  type: "user";
  name: string;
  age: number;
  occupation: string;
}

interface Admin {
  type: "admin";
  name: string;
  age: number;
  role: string;
}

type PowerUser = Omit<User, 'type'> & Omit<Admin, 'type'> & { type: "powerUser"};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnJgCeADhAFzIBEArplFQNz7IhwC2Fy6YUoA5swJx+XEDXYAjaEOQB7BAhok4YYHJCUefEINwBfXLlCRYiFAEEAJu1A4WxMpSpwboJizactvAbJFiEtJQslByADZc2n4GRriOKAAKcgDu0BhYALzIAPK2YAA8GVAANMgA5AnlAHzIAGS5+QXWtiBllaQQNfU4hJ3OJKnp9FT6zLgIGjzIEAAeHCSRlMlpUMXI2XgECQNDayMlLAGUAEwADIcEXlzl7HCz5Zfyisqq6prUAGIAolRPYUtqHcqLEgA)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, but this will make the example not working since the occupation and role is not legit for some reason, I tried to turn it into `User & Admin`, but this won't work.